The correct way to implement nested forms, using react-hook-form
I am developing a React typescript application. I have a form named "Receipts" that I store the purchased receipts from customers. Each receipt has one or more products, So I have a "Product" form too, which is the child of "Receipt" form.
The "Receipt" form contains some inputs, a button to add product, and a data grid to show already added products. When you click on adding a product, the "Product" from opens to allow user add the info of product, then save it. The newly saved product then will be appended to the list of products inside data grid.
Here is the shape of each entity:
interface ReceiptPayload {
    date: string | Date;
    factorNumber: string;
    products: ReceiptProductsPayload[];
}

interface ReceiptProductPayload {
    name: string;
    quantity: number;
}

I am using react-hook-form library to manage the data form. I am confused how to use this library, when to use useForm, useFormContext, and useFieldArray; and I need your help to clarify this for me.
The ReceiptComponent:
const ReceiptComponent = () => {
    const methods = useForm<ReceiptPayload>();
    ...
    return (
        <FormProvider {...methods}>
           <Dialog component='form'>
              <TextFiled {...method.register('date')} />
              <TextFiled {...method.register('factorNumber')} />
              <DataGridBiew // to show the added products ... />
           </Dialog>
           <Button // to open product dialog ... />
           {openProductDialog && <ProductComponent ... />
       </FormProvider>
    );
}

And the ProductComponent component:
const ProductComponent = () => {
    // Q1: should I use useForm or useFormContext here as this form is the child of Receipt form.
   const methods = useForm();
   const methods = useFormContext();

    // Q2: which type should it be? ReceiptPayload or ReceiptProductPayload?
    const methods = useForm<ReceiptProductPayload>();
    const methods = useFormContext<ReceiptProductPayload>();

   const handleProductAppend = () => {
       // Q3: how should I append the product info to the products list in receipt form
       // I need to append this product using the append method from useFieldArray
       // should I pass the append method from ReceiptComponent to this component?
   }

    return (
        // Q4: should I use FormProvider here?
        <Dialog component='form' ... >
           <TextField {...methods.register('name')} />
           <TextField {...methods.register('quantity')} />
           <Button // to save the info of product  onClic={handleProductAppend} />
        </Dialog>
    );
}

My Approach:
I get the append method from useFieldArray in my ReceiptComponent, then I pass it down to ProductComponent.
const methods = useForm<ProductPayload>({
    // I used useForm so I can set default values here
    defaultValues: {
      quantity: 1,
    },
  });

  const handelAddItemClick = () => {
    // I get append method from ReceiptComponent
    apend(methods.getValues());
  };

   return (
       <FormProvider {...methods} ?
          <Dialog component='form' ... >
             <TextField {...methods.register('name')} />
             <TextField {...methods.register('quantity')} />
             <Button // to save the info of product  onClic={handleProductAppend} />
          </Dialog>
       </FormProvider>
    );

Problem:
The problem with my approach is when I save the ProductComponent form, it seems that the ReceiptComponent tries to get submitted, because required fields in ReceiptComponent show me the required error, which is not expected behaviour.
